# Convert PHP chr()/strval() function to C++

Tags: php, c++, code-translation

I'm trying to convert a library of character manipulation from PHP to C++.

1) I've used `static_cast<char>()` to replace all single `chr()` functions (applied only to a single char, ie: `PHP: $out = chr(50); => C++: std::string s = static_cast<char>(50)`).

Is this correct?

2) Given the following PHP code :

```
$crypt = chr(strval(substr("5522446633",0,2)));
```

In this snippet, we extract 2 char from the string "5522446633", and "get their string values" ([PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)) from the function `strval()`.

I know how to get the (integer) value from one char in C++, but how can I do with two chars?

How can I translate this snippet to C++?

Comment: All your questions can be answered by opening your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::string`. `std::string` also has a very similar `substr()` function, and PHP's `strval()` is utterly meaningless in this context. The closest analogue would be `std::string`'s constructor. C++ is not PHP, and it works differently from PHP in fundamental ways. You will only hobble your own understanding of C++ if you attempt to constantly equate it with PHP. Do yourself a favor, and completely forget everything you know about PHP if you are serious about becoming proficient in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : I beg your pardon Sir, but my C++ book tell me how static_cast, std::string and wathever behave, not if my interpretation/translation is correct in this context. I did not ask if I have to forget everything about PHP, I only pointed out that I didn't understand the documentation about the return value of strval("AB"), and how to do the same thing with C++ : is it ASCII value of 'A' + ASCII value of 'B', ASCII value of 'A' on MSB and ASCII value of 'B' on LSB, ASCII 'A' modulo whatever?

Comment: A simple google search for "php strval" immediately finds a full explanation of what "strval()" does in PHP, and it sure would've been much faster than sitting and waiting for someone to respond on stackoverflow.com. strval simply converts some arbitrary PHP variable into a string, and, as I patiently explained, this is what `std::string`'s many constructors do, in general. And in some cases, perhaps, a formatted output operator would be the C++ equivalent. Once again: there is no direct translation, a paint-by-numbers equivalent in C++ of something in PHP. They are fundamentally different.

Comment: `chr("AB")` produces an empty output as "AB" is not a valid number. Are you sure this is the php code you are trying to convert?

Comment: @AlanBirtles : Yes, in the comment of the PHP script, it says `convert char two by two`. This code is taken from a GS1-128 barcode generator.

Comment: If the code in the question isn't the code you want us to convert we wont be able to give you the right answer. We need a [mcve], the equivalent of `$crypt = chr(strval(substr("ABCD",0,2)));` in c++ is `std::string crypt;`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles : I've understand now what this snippet does, the data sent to the `strval()` function were incorrect when I was debugging. Its not a string like `ABCD`, just a string composed by an even set of numbers, like `5522446633`. Should I close or delete this question?

Comment: no need to close or delete the question, just edit it so that it is correct then we can provide the answer. If you already know the answer yourself you can answer your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is equivalent to your php code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string convert(const std::string& value)
{
  size_t pos;
  try
  {
      std::string sub = value.substr(0,2);
      int chr = std::stoi(sub, &pos);
      if (pos != sub.size())
      {
          return "";
      }
      return std::string(1, static_cast<char>(chr & 255));
  }
  catch ( std::exception& )
  {
      return "";
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << convert("5522446633") << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First note that in c++ string type is very different from character type.

Character type is represented as a single 8 bit number.

std::string is a class for representing a string (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for details).

So regarding 1 - your example probably won't work. std::string doesn't accept a single character as a constructor.
You could use the following to create a std::string object with a length of one from a number (using fill constructor described in the reference above):

```
char c = 50;
std::string s(1,c);
```

Regarding 2, not sure what you are trying to achieve, but since C strings are already saved as an array of byte integers you could for example try the following:

```
std:string s = "ABCD"; 
// char* s = "ABCD"; would work the same way in this case
int byte1 = s[0];
int byte2 = s[1];
```

If what you want is to parse hexadecimal string you could use `strtol` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)